# Difficulty with propagating tags in the AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

We're using the AWS CDK to deploy a large part of our infrastructure, including ECS resources. I have a file that creates an ECS cluster, task definition and tasks. Per [the Tag class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_core.Tag.html) I'm then using Tag.add() to apply a tag to everything in the scope of the file, including all ECS resources.

When I deploy the stack, the tag applies to the cluster and the task definition, but not the task. I also don't get any error messages; the tag just silently doesn't apply to the task. Applying tags directly to the task doesn't seem to be a supported workaround so I'm stuck. Does anyone know the solution to get the task tagged?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the ECS patterns constructs (eg, ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService)  you can get this working by adding the following flags:

```
enable_ecs_managed_tags=True,
                                                                              
propagate_tags=aws_ecs.PropagatedTagSource.TASK_DEFINITION,
```

After that point my tags propogated from my CDK stack to the ECS cluster/service/task definitions and then into the underlying tasks.

Comment: This was the correct solution for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Applying tags directly to the task doesn't seem to be a supported workaround so I'm stuck.

I'm not too familiar with ECS tasks, but have you tried to write the tags to the CloudFormation Resource construct directly?

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/cfn_layer.html:

> **Modifying the AWS CloudFormation Resource behind AWS Constructs**
>
> If an [sic] Construct is missing a feature or you are trying to work around an issue, you can modify the CFN Resource that is encapsulated by the Construct.
>
> All Constructs contain within them the corresponding CFN Resource...
>
> The basic approach to get access to the CFN Resource class is to use `construct.node.defaultChild` (Python: `default_child`), cast it to the right type (if necessary), and modify its properties.
>
> **Raw Overrides**
>
> If there are properties that are missing from the CFN Resource, you can bypass all typing using raw overrides. This also makes it possible to delete synthesized properties.
>
> Use one of the `addOverride` methods (Python: `add_override`) methods, as shown in the following example.
>
> ```
> # Get the AWS CloudFormation resource
> cfn_bucket = bucket.node.default_child
>
> # Use dot notation to address inside the resource template fragment
> cfn_bucket.add_override("Properties.VersioningConfiguration.Status", "NewStatus")
> cfn_bucket.add_deletion_override("Properties.VersioningConfiguration.Status")
>
> # add_property_override is a convenience function, which implies the
> # path starts with "Properties."
> cfn_bucket.add_property_override("VersioningConfiguration.Status", "NewStatus")
> cfn_bucket.add_property_deletion_override("VersioningConfiguration.Status")
> ```

Comment: Actually I missed that part of the docs. That looks like it just might work. I'll try it, and thanks for pointing it out!